# Beautifulsoup: Only the first row in the same tr class than others

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm working in a scraping of this web: https://www.resultados-futbol.com/premier/grupo1/jornada1

I'm trying to get the information of one specific row (only the first one) of each match. They are the events (mainly goals) in each game. This is the structure of the web:

[Each tr.vevent is a match and each match includes his events in tr.league-match-events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uzBA.png)

I only need to scrape the info of the first event in each game. Exactly I need to capture if the goal is "1-0" or "0-1" and the minute of the score. This is the code I try to do but it takes ALL the events:

```
for row in soup.select('tr.league-match-events'):
    minute = row.select_one('.lme-minute').get_text()
    gol = row.select_one('.url')
    minutos= []
    
    minutos.append({
        'minutos':minute,
        'goles':gol
    })
```

This is what I get in the minutos list:

```
[{'minutos': "23'", 'goles': <span class="url">1-0</span>}, {'minutos': "38'", 'goles': <span class="url">2-0</span>}, {'minutos': "44'", 'goles': <span class="url">3-0</span>}, {'minutos': "72'", 'goles': <span class="url">4-0</span>}, {'minutos': "78'", 'goles': <span class="url">0-1</span>}, {'minutos': "8'", 'goles': <span class="url">1-0</span>}, {'minutos': "28'", 'goles': <span class="url">2-0</span>}, {'minutos': "36'", 'goles': None}, {'minutos': "41'", 'goles': <span class="url">4-0</span>}, {'minutos': "54'", 'goles': <span class="url">4-1</span>}, {'minutos': "60'", 'goles': <span class="url">5-1</span>}, {'minutos': "71'", 'goles': <span class="url">6-1</span>}, {'minutos': "73'", 'goles': <span class="url">7-1</span>}, {'minutos': "76'", 'goles': <span class="url">8-1</span>}, {'minutos': "90'", 'goles': <span class="url">9-1</span>}, {'minutos': "64'", 'goles': <span class="url">1-0</span>}, {'minutos': "72'", 'goles': <span class="url">2-0</span>}, {'minutos': "29'", 'goles': <span class="url">1-0</span>}, {'minutos': "34'", 'goles': <span class="url">2-0</span>}, {'minutos': "48'", 'goles': <span class="url">3-0</span>}, {'minutos': "68'", 'goles': <span class="url">4-0</span>}, {'minutos': "90'", 'goles': <span class="url">4-1</span>}, {'minutos': "25'", 'goles': <span class="url">1-0</span>}, {'minutos': "64'", 'goles': <span class="url">1-1</span>}, {'minutos': "66'", 'goles': <span class="url">2-1</span>}, {'minutos': "71'", 'goles': <span class="url">3-1</span>}, {'minutos': "94'", 'goles': <span class="url">1-0</span>}, {'minutos': "9'", 'goles': <span class="url">0-1</span>}, {'minutos': "39'", 'goles': <span class="url">0-2</span>}, {'minutos': "61'", 'goles': <span class="url">1-2</span>}, {'minutos': "68'", 'goles': <span class="url">2-2</span>}]
```

They are all the goals and besides it includes the  in each goal. I can't remove it with get_text() because it shows an error.

The result I would like to have is:

```
[{'minutos': "23'", 'goles': 1-0}, {'minutos': "78'", 'goles': 0-1}, {'minutos': "8'", 'goles': 1-0}, {'minutos': "64'", 'goles': 1-0</span}, {'minutos': "29'", 'goles': 1-0}, {'minutos': "25'", 'goles': 1-0}, {'minutos': "94'", 'goles': 1-0</span}, {'minutos': "9'", 'goles': 0-1}]
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your example works for me (with get_text() ). Can you show the error? I'm using 'lxml' parser for BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you get a complete `list` cause in your example it is overwriting itself, maybe a typo.

### How to get only the first goal in match?

A very simple approach to get the goals is to check if there is a `0-1` or `1-0` in the result and then only append these to the `list`:

```
if '0-1' in gol or '1-0' in gol:
            minutos.append({
                'minutos':minute,
                'goles':gol
            })
```

Another is to `select` the next sibling of the `tr` with the match data and it is maybe what you are questioning:

```
soup.select('tr.vevent + tr.league-match-events')
```

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
url = 'https://www.resultados-futbol.com/premier/grupo1/jornada1'
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser') # I have to use Selenium previously cos I have to expand some buttons in the web

minutos=[]

for row in soup.select('tr.vevent + tr.league-match-events'):
    minute = row.select_one('.lme-minute').get_text()
    gol = row.select_one('.url').get_text()
    
    minutos.append({
        'minutos':minute,
        'goles':gol
    })
minutos
```

**Output**

```
[{'minutos': "9'", 'goles': '0-1'},
 {'minutos': "13'", 'goles': '1-0'},
 {'minutos': "4'", 'goles': '1-0'},
 {'minutos': "56'", 'goles': '0-1'},
 {'minutos': "57'", 'goles': '0-1'},
 {'minutos': "55'", 'goles': '0-1'},
 {'minutos': "3'", 'goles': '0-1'},
 {'minutos': "23'", 'goles': '0-1'},
 {'minutos': "71'", 'goles': '0-1'},
 {'minutos': "79'", 'goles': '1-0'}]
```

Comment: Fantastic. It really solved what I wanted. The key has been the "+" in the both tr. Thanks a lot for all your help!